# Creating tables using Hibernate for annotated classes

Tags: hibernate

I'm getting below error. What might be the reason? Help me through this.

I'm Inside Test class

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.SecondPass.doSecondPass(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:315)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1156)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
at com.mindtree.test.Test.main(Test.java:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excepction says java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Meaning at run time the required method is not found. The problem could be some hibernate JAR files missing .

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I tried with different set of jars and the problem got fixed.